# ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE turns red after upgrading to android studio 3.6.1

Tags: android, android-studio-3.6

I'm just upgrading my android studio to 3.6.1 but I've got a new warning about the orientation which is a new issue for me. The IDE suggested me to set my orientation to `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED` but I don't know if the suggested orientation is the right way I needed. Does anybody know how to rid of this red underline?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a lint warning, not an error, and you can ignore the warning if you don't want to follow the advice.

To suppress the lint warning in java code, you can add

```
//noinspection AndroidLintSourceLockedOrientationActivity
```

on the line just above the warning.

In kotlin (works also in java) have to add

```
@SuppressLint("SourceLockedOrientationActivity")
```

annotation e.g. on the method level. Personally I prefer to make the suppression scopes to be as narrow as possible.